# Initial delay in typing

Tags: fedora, delay

I've noticed after I come back to my newly installed Fedora 20 system, there's a delay in typing.

For example, if I have a terminal window open, and I leave it alone for a few minutes and return, when I type, it takes multiple seconds for my typing to manifest.  It's fine after that, provided I don't wait too long between typing.  This happens for any typing, not just the terminal.  It could be the password on the lock screen, terminal sessions, web forms in FireFox, etc.

My system has 32G of RAM, and it occurs with nothing active, except for a terminal or webpage, nothing significantly taxing.

The keyboard is the build in laptop physical keyboard.

The laptop is a Dell Inspiron 17R (17RM-16452sLV).

Is there a known reason this occurs? How can I diagnose and fix the cause of the issue?

Comment: Is your system low on memory? Maybe the terminal gets swapped out. You can leave a top running (in some other terminal), to check.

Comment: I'm willing to bet you're using a wireless keyboard?

Comment: @Anthon 32G of RAM with nothing running, top indicates nothing intensive is running.

Comment: @mikeserv I'm using the normal physical laptop keyboard, nothing special.

Comment: What is your laptop model? Might be driver-related issue.

Comment: @edvinas.me It's a Dell Inspiron 17R.

Comment: Probably acpi then.

Comment: mikserv has a good point.  Does the normal suspend work properly -- e.g., if you suspend without putting the lid down, does the screen blank?

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks'Yes, if I suspend using the physical power button, it goes down normally, and comes back as expected when you press it again.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' Actually, I left it suspended overnight and resumed it just now.  Before the splash screen with the time came up, there was some text indicating something about failure to resume, error -19.  It went away too quickly to see more detail than that, but it appeared to have been repeated 3 or 4 times on that screen.

Comment: Try switching to a VT (non GUI "virtual terminal", e.g. ctrl-alt-F4) and see if the same thing happens there.  This will at least provide a clue as to whether it is a kernel driver, or some userland thing run by the GUI DE ("desktop environment").

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' Switching to a VT, I don't encounter the issue.  Switching back from a VT to my GUI window, typing doesn't register at all for 3 or 4 seconds.

Comment: Also, scrolling on web pages sometimes takes several seconds to take effect, as well.  I know the wireless mouse I'm using works perfectly on other systems.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reinstalling with Fedora 20 XFCE Spin.  The phenomenon completely vanished, and XFCE is vastly more responsive in general than Gnome.  As I followed an otherwise identical installation process, I have to assume it was either Gnome 3 causing the issue, or Gnome 3 having an argument with my hardware that XFCE didn't have.